# C++ : includes when code is written in text editor, linux

Tags: c++, compilation, include, text-editor

I'm only a couple of weeks self-starter with C++. During the interview I will be asked to write a simple task in the text editor and compile it, to start with I need to include C++ libraries, I know how to do it in IDE but how do I do it in the text editor, can anyone help?

Comment: Open your text editor, type stuff, save it as a file named e.g. `foo.cpp`, compile it, fix errors, test, debug, lather, rinse, repeat...

Comment: I do it exactly step by step but it gives back errors that don’t make sense, beside the same stuff works perfectly in windows visual studio, as far as I can understand it's a including s problem.

Comment: The errors may not make sense to *you*, but that's no reason to keep them secret.

Comment: if you tell me how to post the code here I could show that everything is fine with the code

Comment: @MartaGinosian add an extra indent to all the code you want to post, and then just copy and paste it in

Comment: @Josh "extra indent" ? I'm sorry for this kind of questions, I'm new here , but to add where from ? I see only "Add Comment"

Comment: @MartaGinosian There's an `edit` link under your question which should allow you to update the text of your question.  You can use that to include the command you're using to compile as well as the errors that you're getting.  After you enter that information, you can select it all with your mouse and click the `{}` button to indicate that the text is pre-formatted (code).

Comment: @MartaGinosian of what type is `array`? You need to include a type in the definition (ie: `int array[]` or `char array[]`). Also, you need to include `random` to get the `srand` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would add them as you normally would...

However, if the header files don't reside in the same directory that you are working from you might need to issue an additional command to g++ when compiling.

```
g++ -o new_file_name -I /header/file/directory file.cpp
```

This will tell the compiler to look for `#include`s in the `/header/file/directory` and include them while compiling `file.cpp`.

Libraries can be included in the same way by using the `-L` flag instead of `-I`.

Comment: marta@marta-HP-ProBook-455-G1:~/Documents/ArrayFunctionCollection$ g++ -o header.h -I /header/file/directory header.h
header.h:3:19: fatal error: tchar.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
The bug is not reproducible, so it is likely a hardware or OS problem.
marta@marta-HP-ProBook-455-G1:~/Documents/ArrayFunctionCollection$ ^C
marta@marta-HP-ProBook-455-G1:~/Documents/ArrayFunctionCollection$

Comment: this what is it gave back

Comment: I should have been more clear - the new_file_name is what you want to call your newly compiled file. You don't want to put the name of the header file in that spot. So if your .cpp file is named foo.cpp and you want it to have the name foo once it compiles you would issue the command:  g++ -o foo -I /header/file/directory foo.cpp

Comment: @MartaGinosian That does show, however, exactly what I was describing in my answer.  `tchar.h` (and the types it defines) isn't a standard header file.  It is specific to Microsoft's C++ implementation, so you're not going to be able to use that on non-Windows systems.

Comment: no, it did not work or I did something wrong

Comment: marta@marta-HP-ProBook-455-G1:~/Documents/ArrayFunctionCollection$ g++ -o Array -I header Array.cpp
Array.cpp:7:16: error: variable or field ‘InitArray’ declared void
 void InitArray(array[]);
                ^
Array.cpp:7:16: error: ‘array’ was not declared in this scope
Array.cpp:7:22: error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token
 void InitArray(array[]);
                      ^
Array.cpp:8:17: error: variable or field ‘PrintArray’ declared void
 void PrintArray(array[]);


                ^
and so on

Comment: I exclude #include "targetver.h" and #include <tchar.h> too

Answer (score 6):

`tchar.h` is a Microsoft-specific header file, so you're at least seeing an error like the one below when you try to compile with `g++`

```
foo.cpp:1:19: error: tchar.h No such file or directory
```

You're likely seeing a whole host of other errors related to the fact that all of your code which uses stuff defined in `tchar.h` is using undefined data types.

Comment: @MartaGinosian The same about `targetver.h` - it's usualy Visual Studio's generated file and filled with Microsoft specific stuff. So try to comment out both include-s and compile.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple really.  Add these lines to the top of your `.cpp` or `.h` file:

```
#include "targetver.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
```

... and you're done!

Comment: compilers doesn't seem to recognize when I add those